# How to stop Logitech MX Master 3 mouse from disconnecting from Bluetooth?

Tags: windows-10, mouse, bluetooth, connection, logitech-mouse

Using the latest Windows 10, this mouse keeps disconnecting, usually upon exiting sleep mode. **But sometimes even in the middle of usage!**

I've noticed it happens much less after the computer gets restarted. The more the computer stays on, the more likely it is to happen.

Also, it seems to happen a lot while moving the mouse during videos.

Contacting Logitech was futile. But their products usually work super well, so hopefully this can be solved.

Comment: I recommend using the receiver.

There is at least one other reason why I advise against working with Bluetooth and the mouse: On an iMac, the keyboard and mouse via Bluetooth only work as expected after the login screen. When using the receiver, they already work on the login screen.

Comment: Thanks! But since it's Windows 10, it's much easier with BT, as it leaves the USB port open for other needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until it's fixed, I found some methods to wake it up again. Sometimes only some of them work, but anyway here they are by order of comfort and speed (if any of them works, there's no need to proceed to the next trick):

1. Entering Windows' `Bluetooth & other devices` settings, then closing it without doing anything!
2. Entering Windows' `Bluetooth & other devices` settings, turning the general Bluetooth setting to **Off**, then **On** again.
3. Entering Windows' `Bluetooth & other devices` settings, clicking `Remove device` on the mouse, then re-pair it.
4. Turning the mouse's power button **off**, then **on**.

Comment: not working in my case with windows 11

Answer (score 4):

Had same frustrating problem myself,
Solved it by entering into device manager,Bluetooth, and looking for bluetooth radio driver (mine is called Intel Wireless Bluetooth),
Right click, then click on power management tab and Uncheck the first option “Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power”

Been working flawless since.

Comment: The question is did you also experience interruptions also in the middle of usage like in this question. If you did, your solution is not supposed to fix those ones.

Comment: yes, i did. but, it started disconnecting again....lol.

Comment: In if started disconnecting again, please delete your answer since you seem to state it didn't solve it after all.

Comment: this solution does not change anything